# Can I enter Croatia providing a bus ticket to Slovenia as proof of onward travel?

Tags: international-travel, borders, denial-of-entry

I am a brazilian going to travel to some places in Europe, but I don't have my entire itinerary planed yet. All I have right now is my flight ticket to Croatia, and a bus ticket to Slovenia (from Croatia). I also already rent an accomodation in Croatia.

I know I can stay in Croatia without a visa for 90 max, but I also know that the border may require a proof of return to Brazil or onward travel to let me in.

I would like to know if my bus ticket to Slovenia is enough proof for the border officer to let me in.

I am in Bangkok now, in case it is important.

**Edit**

I already checked a lot of resources on the internet, and from my understanding, the bus ticket is enough, because Croatia is outside of Schengen. I am only asking this because I just check in for the flight, and the girl from the air company said that maybe they will deny my entry there because I don't have the return ticket to Brazil (she let me check in and I am taking the flight normally though), but that goes against everything that I found on the internet, so maybe I missed something :(

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.mvep.hr/en/consular-information/visas/visa-requirements-overview/brazil,36.html#p) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Brazilian_citizens) can help you

Comment: Hey, thank you for the links, but I already came across those in my research (see my edit)

Comment: The Croatian visa requirements page does not list any proof of onward travel, neither does Timatic.  I didn't have any on my arrival.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Johns-305. I that's what I thought when I saw the page, but the lady from the air company got me really worried now T-T. But knowing that you didn't need to provide the proof of onward travel is a relief, maybe she just is just missinformed lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Croatia does not require proof of onward travel which matches my own experience. I used an open-jaw ticket to reach Croatia but immigration never asked to see anything more than the passport. A few weeks later I returned to Croatia by car and they did not ask any proof of onward travel. Days later I did go back via train and no return ticket was asked for. So 3 times in and not once did they ask for proof of onward or return travel.

Comment: Just like you said, they didn't ask for it at the border. Thank you!